# multiple looped values in ajax call and controller function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm having an issue in laravel with sending multiple input options (built by a foreach loop) into an ajax call so that I could send multiple values and loop them in the ajax call in order to properly send them to the controller. I need to call a stored procedure for each set of attributes so that if they choose 3 options, the ajax call would send them all and I would call the stored procedure 3 times for those values.

The blade:

```
@foreach($getRuleAttributes as $attributes)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><label>{{ $attributes->title }}</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="attribute_data"></td>
        <input type="hidden" class="attribute_id" value="{{ $attributes->attributet_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" class="attribute_type" value="promo_codes">
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This gives one input and then multiple options with checkboxes where multiple can be selected

ajax portion of blade:

```
 $("#savePromoCode").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    /********************************/
    /*This is where the issue starts*/
        var attr_title
        var attr_type_name
        var attr_value
    /*******************************/


    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'postData',
       data:{rule_name:rule_name, attr_title:attr_title, attr_type_name:attr_type_name, attr_value:attr_value},
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    });
});
```

Controller.php

```
public function postContent(Request $request)
    {
        $attr_title = $request->attr_title;
        $attr_type_name = $request->attr_type_name;
        $attr_value = $request->attr_value;

        $callProcedure = new procedureService();
        $ruleSave = $callProcedure->saveFunction($attr_title,$attr_type_name,$attr_value);
    }
```

My main question here, is if I have multiple attr_title, attr_type_name and attr_value then how exactly would I reconcile this in my ajax call and the controller? The variables are built by a php foreach, so if they select 3 of these then I would need the ajax call to send all three and the controller would call the stored procedure 3 times in order to get them all inserted.

How exactly would I do this?

Comment: Add the name attr with array, like attr_title[], attr_type_name[]. in ajax using serialize(); send the multi select value to  controller.

Comment: Would I need a foreach in my JS in order to do the serialize properly? Also, the form is only around what I already posted, I just didn't add the button

Comment: in js you need to use form.serialize(); and in controller use parse_str to get the all the data in array. after that use the foreach loop and call the procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change name attr to array []. form will be like**

```
<form id="form">
<?php $i = 1; ?>
@foreach($getRuleAttributes as $attributes)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['checked']"></td>
        <input type="text" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['attribute_title']" value="{{ $attributes->title }}">
        <input type="text" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['attributet_id']" value="{{ $attributes->attributet_id }}">
        <input type="text" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['attribute_type']" value="attribute_type1">
    </tr>
<?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="savePromoCode">
```

**jQuery code**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#savePromoCode").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();

        //using serialize send the from data to ajax request file
        var form_data = jQuery("#form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'postData',
           data:{form_data:form_data,
            _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'

        }

        });
    });
});

</script>
```

**In controller using [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) get the serialize value in array.**

```
 public function postContent(Request $request){
    $form_data = $request->form_data;
    parse_str($form_data, $my_array_of_vars);
    $attr = $my_array_of_vars['attribute'];

    /*echo "<pre>";
    print_r($attr);*/

    foreach($attr as $key=>$value){

        //get the value of checked row - attribute_title, attributet_id, attribute_type, Confirm what attr you need use that one
        if(isset($value["'checked'"]) && $value["'checked'"] != ''){
            echo $attribute_title = $value["'attribute_title'"];
            echo $attributet_id1 = $value["'attributet_id'"];
            echo $attribute_type1 = $value["'attribute_type'"];
            $callProcedure = new procedureService();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you however this dumps every checkbox value, how can I do this with only those checked?

Comment: Check the form  I added. It will take only checked row value.

Answer (score 1):

You neen to send an array of values instead of sending it row by row.

try to compile your data into one array

```
$("#savePromoCode").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    /********************************/
    /*This is where the issue starts*/
        var attributes = [];
           ... //foreach there
        var item = {
          title = YOUR_TITLE,
          type_name = YOUR_TYPE_NAME,
          value = YOUR_TYPE_VALUE
        };
        attributes[] = item;
    /*******************************/


    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'postData',
       data:{rule_name:rule_name, attributes:attributes},
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    });
});
```

And then in your controller

```
$callProcedure = new procedureService();

foreach ($request->input('attributes') as $attribute){
    $callProcedure->saveFunction(
        $attribute['title'],
        $attribute['type_name'],
        $attribute['value']
    );
}
```

Comment: would I just use the same foreach as I did in my php then?